# RL Circuit with Time-Dependent Switch

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, inductance

We are currently studying RC, RL and RLC circuit but I am having a hard time comprehending some topics, like what is the function and importance of putting a 0 V source in series with the inductor in the RL circuit below?
[image]

Comment: Context is needed here: where did the schematic come from? What are its origins?

Comment: It is used to demonstrate the transient response of RL Circuit

Answer (score 1):

For spice simulations, sometimes a 0V voltage source is added in order to measure current through a component. In this case, it's the inductor.

Comment: We are using multisim in our simulations, is it the same case?

Comment: @nanashi Multisim uses SPICE underneath, so probably "yes".  Although, Multisim additionally has an "ammeter" device which you can use for this as well, however the nice thing about the 0V voltage source is it's guaranteed to be ideal without any series resistance.  I have no idea what non-idealities the ammeter block has, if any.  I think if you have any follow-up questions, you need to ask your teacher/professor or whomever constructed the circuit.